# TypeError: filter.split is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: javascript

> `
> **ERROR
> [Function (anonymous)]
> TypeError: filter.split is not a function or its return value is not iterable
> at Object.getFilterString (/cb-api/helpers/processQuery/index.js:341:42)
> at get (/cb-api/routes/v3/data-browser-configurations/index.js:66:50)
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) Unhandled Rejection at Promise Promise {
>  TypeError: filter.split is not a function or its return value is not iterable
> at Object.getFilterString (/cb-api/helpers/processQuery/index.js:341:42)
> at get (/cb-api/routes/v3/data-browser-configurations/index.js:66:50)
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)**

`

```
getFilterString: (parameters, excludedParametersArray = []) => {
        let searchQuery = ''
        // Build query
        for (column in parameters) {
            let filter = parameters[column]
            let valueList = ''
            let columnString = ''
            let count = 0

            if (filter == '' || filter == null || typeof filter !== 'string') {
                return 'You have provided invalid values for filter.'
            } else {
                // Check if the column is not excluded in the filter
                if (!excludedParametersArray.includes(column)) {
                    if (column.includes('Timestamp')) {
                        // Set filter for columns with timestamp
                        // Given must be in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format
                        columnString = `to_char("` + column + `",'yyyy-mm-dd')`
                    } else if (column.toUpperCase() == column) {
                        // Filter the variables
                        // All the variable abbrev are in Uppercase
                        columnString = `lower("` + column + `"->>'variableValue')`
                    } else if (column == 'fieldLocation') {
                        // Set filter for fieldLocation
                        columnString = `lower("` + column + `"->>'display_name')`
                    } else if (column == 'parentage') {
                        // Set filter for parentage
                        columnString = `RTRIM(lower("` + column + `"))`
                    } else {
                        // default
                        columnString = `lower("` + column + `"::text)`
                    }
                    console.log(filter)
                    // Parse the value
                    for (value of filter.split('|')) {
                        valueList += "$$" + (value.trim()).toLowerCase() + "$$,"
                        count++
                    }

                    // Set the condition
                    let condition = ''
                    if (count > 1) {
                        // For multiple values
                        valueList = valueList.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "")

                        condition = columnString
                            + ` IN (`
                            + valueList
                            + `)`
                    } else {
                        // For single values
                        if (columnString.includes('Id')) {
                            // Search for exact values if the column name includes 'Id'
                            condition = columnString
                                + ` = '`
                                + value
                                + `'`
                        } else {
                            // Search for ilike values if the column name does not include 'Id'
                            condition = columnString
                                + ` ILIKE '`
                                + value
                                + `%' `
                        }
                    }

                    // Set the condition based on the parameters
                    if (searchQuery == '') {
                        searchQuery = searchQuery +
                            ` WHERE `
                            + condition
                    } else {
                        searchQuery = searchQuery +
                            ` AND `
                            + condition
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return searchQuery
    },
```

`

Comment: Do you have the output of the console.log(filter), please?
This should be the problem because your code is functional even on empty string...
Should your 'of' being the rxjs operator imported by mistake maybe?

Comment: @GregB.  there pal, when i removed the typeof filter ='string' the error occurs, thanks pal